# Hide app from taskbar

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to get my application hidden to systray and the systray thing works fine, except my app won't disspaear from the taskbar. The icon seem to dissapear, but another icon pops up and when I click to show that window I get a windowframe but the contents aren't drawn.

```
def hideEvent(self, event):
    self.trayIcon.show()
    self.hide()
```

How does this not hide my window from the taskbar? It seems like the window contents are hidden but not the window itself. I'm running Windows 7.

Here's a screen showing how it looks after I've minimized it and then click on the icon that seem to pop up:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which GUI-Toolkit are we talking about? More context, please.

Comment: I thought the pyqt4 tag said that, I'm using PyQt4.

Answer (score 0):

You could try also calling the super-class' version of the method you override. Try something like

```
def hideEvent(self, event):
    self.trayIcon.show()
    return super(MyClass, self).hideEvent(event)
```

where MyClass is the name of the class where you override the hideEvent meth

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI event loop is stuck somewhere and is unable to update itself. Are you doing some long-running computation or something similar?

Comment: That sadly doesn't mean anything :/

Comment: Since it works on Linux I'm not running some long-running computation or similar. I keep that kind of thing in other threads to avoid locking up the gui.